# GROUP BY also SELECT non-constant columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables in my database:

```
log_visitors:
--------------------
id | host_id


log_access:
--------------------
visitor | document | timestamp
```

`log_access.visitor` links to `log_visitors.id`

Currently, I'm using this query:

```
SELECT
    log_visitors.host_id
    , MIM(log_access.timestamp) AS min_timestamp
FROM
    log_access
    INNER JOIN log_visitors
        ON (log_access.visitor = log_visitors.id)
GROUP BY log_visitors.host_id;
```

to get `MIN(timestamp)` for each `host_id` in the database.

Here's my question:

I also need to get `document` for that access with that timestamp... I can't simply add `log_access.document` into SELECT list, since it's not constant and I am not grouping by document...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You didn't specify your DBMS, but this is ANSI SQL (which works in most modern DBMS)

```
select *
from (
  SELECT log_visitors.host_id,
         log_visitors.document,
         log_access.timestamp
         min(log_access.timestamp) OVER (partition by log_visitors.host_id) AS min_timestamp
  FROM log_access
    JOIN log_visitors ON (log_access.visitor = log_visitors.id)
) t
where t.timestamp = t.min_timestamp
ORDER BY host_id
```

Comment: Doesn't the subquery need a `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @ypercube: no it doesn't. That's what windowing functions are for.

Comment: @dash: Please, undelete your answer. One reason is that some DBMS (like MySQL) do not have window functions. The second is that your query may even perform better in some situations (or with not mature optimizers).

Comment: @ypercube Have done - I'm never really sure of the etiquette in these situations though. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 3):

Something like the following should give you what you want:

```
SELECT      lv.host_id,
            mv.MinTime,
            la.document

FROM        log_visitors AS lv
INNER JOIN     
            (SELECT visitor, 
                    MIN(timestamp) AS MinTime 
             FROM log_access 
             GROUP BY visitor) AS mv ON lv.id = mv.visitor
INNER JOIN  log_access AS la ON lv.id = la.visitor AND mv.MinTime = la.timestamp
```

What we do is get a list of all visitors and the min timestamps in a table, join onto that, then join back onto log access on the timestamp to select the particular document.

This uses ANSI SQL-92 so should work across a wide range database systems, including those that don't support windowing functions.

Here's an example of the query in action via [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f791d/8)

Comment: Thanks, this really helped! My server is MySQL (OVER/PARTITION BY didn't work). Now I'm trying to figure out, how to also get MAX(timestamp) with appropriate document number (so my result table has columns like "MinTime, MaxTime, MinDocument, MaxDocument, id". Found a solution with one more JOIN, but it looks too
laborious...

Comment: @MichalKosek an extra join sounds right for that so don't worry about it!